# Delaying array size in class definition in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, size, delay

Is there some way to delay defining the size of an array until a class method or constructor?

What I'm thinking of might look something like this, which (of course) doesn't work:

```
class Test
{
    private:
    int _array[][];

    public:
    Test::Test(int width, int height);
};

Test::Test(int width, int height)
{
    _array[width][height];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What Daniel is talking about is that you will need to allocate memory for your array dynamically when your Test (width, height) method is called.

You would declare your two dimensional like this (assuming array of integers):

```
int ** _array;
```

And then in your Test method you would need to first allocate the array of pointers, and then for each pointer allocate an array of integers:

```
_array = new  *int [height];
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    _array [i] = new int[width];
}
```

And then when the object is released you will need to explicit delete the memory you allocated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    delete [] _array[i];
    _array [i] = NULL;
}
delete [] _array;
_array = NULL;
```

Comment: Could add the pointer array allocation: _array = new int[height]; Upvoted for providing source though!

Comment: Oops.  Thanks Daniel.  I forgot to add that :). Cheers.

Comment: The problem with manuall arrays managment is the fact you
need to create your own copy constructors/operator = or
make class explictly non-copyable to prevent future problems

Comment: I realize it is years later, but I would just like to point out (as it took me about half an hour of googling to figure it out :P)
That 
    "_array = new *int [height]"
Should really be 
    " _array = new int*[height]' "
Otherwise you will run into a compiler error (using -W -Wextra -Wall -pedantic). :)

Answer (score 8):

vector is your best friend

```
class Test
{
    private:
    vector<vector<int> > _array;

    public:
    Test(int width, int height) :
        _array(width,vector<int>(height,0))
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Artyom is absolutely right.  Save yourself a whole pile of pain :).  However, I guess it is good to understand the underlying principles.

Comment: In terms of data structures, it looks like a vector is still structurally an array but wrapped into a class. Yeah?

Comment: Yes, most vector implementations use arrays 'behind the scenes' I think. You can also use the array operators to manipulate a vector.

Comment: In fact a vector *must* use an array to store the data.  The standard dictates that the elements in a vector be contiguous.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is time for you to look up the new/delete operators.

Seeing as this is a multidimensional array, you're going to have to loop through calling 'new' as you go (and again not to forget: delete).

Although I am sure many will suggest to use a one-dimensional array with width*height elements.

Answer (score 1):

(Months later) one can use templates, like this:

```
// array2.c
// http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html
// is professional, this just shows the principle

#include <assert.h>

template<int M, int N>
class Array2 {
public:
    int a[M][N];  // vla, var-len array, on the stack -- works in gcc, C99, but not all

    int* operator[] ( int j )
    {
        assert( 0 <= j && j < M );
        return a[j];
    }

};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Array2<10, 20> a;
    for( int j = 0; j < 10; j ++ )
    for( int k = 0; k < 20; k ++ )
        a[j][k] = 0;

    int* failassert = a[10];

}
```